# Simplification of an expression of a double integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Is the following expression able to be simplified? 
$$I = \int_0^{x/2} \int_0^s f(s,r)\,dr\,ds + \int_{x/2}^x \int_{2s - x}^s f(s,r)\,dr\,ds . $$
Here $f(s,r)=u(r,2s+x-r)$ so that we could also write
$$I = \int_0^{x/2} \int_0^s u(r,2s+x-r)\,dr\,ds + \int_{x/2}^x \int_{2s - x}^s u(r,2s+x-r)\,dr\,ds . $$
$u$ is unknown.
I made a lot a variables substitutions but without any success. I feel that I can simplify it much more than that. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what $f$ is? If so, can you please write it out: $f(s,r)=\dots?$

Comment: Yes, $f(s,r)=u(r,2s+x-r)$ for certain function $u$.

Comment: Ok, what's $u?$ Can you write out what $u$ is?

Comment: No sir, it is uknown.

Comment: For what it's worth, changing the order of integration results in this: \begin{align*}\int_0^{x/2}\int_0^sdr\,ds&=\int_0^{x/2}\int_r^{x/2}ds\,dr \\ \int_{x/2}^x\int_{2s-x}^sdr\,ds&=\int_0^{x/2}\int_{x/2}^{(r+x)/2}ds\,dr+\int_{x/2}^x\int_r^{(r+x)/2}ds\,dr.\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

With $s$ as the horizontal axis and $r$ as the vertical axis, the region of integration is as in the diagram:

[image: Region of integration]

So reversing the order of integration allows the integral to be written as the single double integral

$$ I=\int_0^x\int_r^{(r+x)/2}f(s,r)\,dsdr $$